# How to initialize a dynamic 2D array using memset?

Tags: c++

What's wrong with this little program? I cannot get the correct answer. I just use m[1][1] to test but it's always 0!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    int **m;
    m = new int*[5];
    for( int i = 0 ; i < 5; i++ )
    {
        m[i] = new int[5];
        memset(m[i],1,sizeof(int)*5);   
    }

    printf("%f",*(*(m+1)+1));
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Passing the wrong type to a variadic function is undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is "not C++". Yes, it's a C++ code, but it isn't using reasonable C++ idioms -- you're mixing C-style `memset` and pointer chasing with `operator new` (which is the only C++ feature you hapen to use). I will therefore assume that you have a reason to use code like that. If you don't have that, seriously consider using some STL class like a `vector` and avoid pointer manipulation.

If you used a reasonable compiler and added reasonable warnings, you would get the error immediately:

```
$ g++ -Wall pwn.cpp
pwn.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
pwn.cpp:14:28: warning: format ‘%f’ expects argument of type ‘double’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat]
```

The correct argument to `printf` for printing ints is `%d`. How does it look after changing that?

```
$ ./a.out 
16843009
```

How come it doesn't print `1`? The `memset` function sets memory, it does not initialize integers. And indeed, `0x01010101 == 16843009`. This is not portable and very likely not what you want to do. Just don't do this, seriously.

Comment: Declaring variables after calling functions is also C++. `for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)` is invalid in C, because you can't declare `i` there.

Comment: @Havenard mixing variable declarations and code (as the ``int i`` inside the ``for`` loop) is actually valid C99 code. You are right in that this was not allowed in earlier versions of the C standard, thanks for pointing that out.

References: ``gcc`` says ``error: ‘for’ loop initial declarations are only allowed in C99 mode`` and ``note: use option -std=c99 or -std=gnu99 to compile your code``.